# alpha blending using openCV

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, alphablending

I am trying to blend 2 ROIs together. One is the ROI of a grayscale image and the other the the ROI of a binary image which I inverted using cvNot in order to get the object as white and the background as black. The output I want is the opposite of what I am getting right now with my code. In the pic, the binary image is put over the grayscale image but I want it to be the other way around so that where is currently white in the pic would be the grayscaled body and the grayscaled background would then be black.
[image: alpha blended output]

This is my code. Please would someone go through it and tell me what needs to be changed to get the output I described above? I would really, really appreciate it.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv ) {

CvCapture *capture = NULL;
capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("C:\\walking\\lady walking.avi");
if(!capture){
    return -1;
}

IplImage* color_frame = NULL ;
IplImage* new_frame = NULL ; 
    IplImage* res_frame = NULL;
int thresh = 17;    

int frameCount=0;//Counts every 5 frames
cvNamedWindow( "contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

while(1) {
    color_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );//Grabs the frame from a file
    if( !color_frame ) break;

    new_frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(color_frame->width, color_frame->height), color_frame->depth, 1);
    if( !color_frame ) break;// If the frame does not exist, quit the loop

    res_frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(color_frame->width, color_frame->height), color_frame->depth, 1);

    frameCount++;
    if(frameCount==5)
    {
        cvCvtColor(color_frame, new_frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvThreshold(new_frame, res_frame, thresh, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        cvErode(res_frame, res_frame, NULL, 1);
        cvDilate(res_frame, res_frame, NULL, 1);
        cvNot (res_frame, res_frame);

        int x = 75;
        int y = 5;
        int width = 125;
        int height = 1500;

        double alpha = 1;
        double beta = 1;

        cvSetImageROI(res_frame, cvRect(x, y, width, height));
        cvSetImageROI(new_frame, cvRect(x, y, width, height));

        //cvResetImageROI(new_frame);
        cvAddWeighted(res_frame, alpha, new_frame, beta, 0.0, res_frame);
        cvShowImage("contours", res_frame);

         frameCount=0;
    }
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if( c == 27 ) break;
}

cvReleaseImage(&color_frame);
cvReleaseImage(&new_frame);
cvReleaseImage(&res_frame);
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "contours" );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://pytech-solution.blogspot.com/2018/02/fast-pixel-processing-with-opencv-and.html uou can also take reference from here , but it is written in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your threshold function I assume that you want to see the black/dark-grey part of the image.
Instead of cvAddWeighted you can use res_frame as a mask for selecting the relevant part of new_frame like this:

```
cvCopy(new_frame,new2_frame,res_frame);
```

With masked copy you create a duplicate of new_frame in new2_frame only at those pixels where res_frame is not zero. new2_frame needs to be the same size as new_frame or the same roi size if you still need roi.

Comment: I followed your advice but I got an error saying : Unhandled exception at 0x767db9bc in 3020 project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0039f98c. Also, No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed. My code is too long to be put in the comment so I posted it as an answer to the question. Please take a look at it and see if this is what you meant for me to try.

Answer (score 1):

@rics, Is this what you meant?

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char* argv ) {

CvCapture *capture = NULL;
capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("C:\\walking\\lady walking.avi");
if(!capture){
    return -1;
}

IplImage* color_frame = NULL ;
IplImage* new_frame = NULL ; 
IplImage* res_frame = NULL;
IplImage* new2_frame = NULL ;
int thresh = 17;    

int frameCount=0;//Counts every 5 frames
cvNamedWindow( "contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

while(1) {
    color_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );//Grabs the frame from a file
    if( !color_frame ) break;

    new_frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(color_frame->width, color_frame->height), color_frame->depth, 1);
    if( !color_frame ) break;// If the frame does not exist, quit the loop

    res_frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(color_frame->width, color_frame->height), color_frame->depth, 1);
    new2_frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(color_frame->width, color_frame->height), color_frame->depth, 1);


    frameCount++;
    if(frameCount==5)
    {
        cvCvtColor(color_frame, new_frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvThreshold(new_frame, res_frame, thresh, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        cvErode(res_frame, res_frame, NULL, 1);
        cvDilate(res_frame, res_frame, NULL, 1);
        cvNot (res_frame, res_frame);

        int x = 75;
        int y = 5;
        int width = 125;
        int height = 1500;

        //double alpha = 1;
        //double beta = 1;

        cvSetImageROI(res_frame, cvRect(x, y, width, height));
        cvSetImageROI(new_frame, cvRect(x, y, width, height));

        //cvResetImageROI(new_frame);
        //cvAddWeighted(res_frame, alpha, new_frame, beta, 0.0, res_frame);
        cvCopy(new_frame,new2_frame,res_frame);
        cvShowImage("contours", new2_frame);

         frameCount=0;
    }
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if( c == 27 ) break;
}

cvReleaseImage(&color_frame);
cvReleaseImage(&new_frame);
cvReleaseImage(&res_frame);
cvReleaseImage(&new2_frame);
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "contours" );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is almost OK but you need to have same sized images for copy, so set the image roi for new2_frame as well after the 2 cvSetImageROI lines: cvSetImageROI(new2_frame, cvRect(x, y, width, height));

Comment: @rics thank you very much sir. That got rid of the error. Now the output is a black body on a gray background but I'll fiddle with the code and try to get the output I want. Thanks again